# Rails Active Storage creating a direct download link

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activestorage

I'm using Active Storage with Rails 5.2.

When I create a download link for an image, it generates an URL for the blob that points to the rails application.

Is there any way to create a download link that directory points to a cloud service like S3 without redirecting to the rails application?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can get the link of the file by using ActiveStorage `service_url` method like this:

```
Model.last.attachment.service_url
```

It will return the service link for your attachment. You can read more about `service_url` [here](https://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveStorage/Variant.html)

Answer (score 3):

**create a link from outside of controller/view context (Background jobs, Cronjobs, etc.), you can access the rails_blob_path like this:**

Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_path(user.avatar, only_path: true)

**and if you want to generate url to download the attached file then use the command:**

Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(user.avatar, only_url: true)

and replace **(user.avatar)** with your **model.activeStorageObject**

Answer (score 1):

`service_url` method is the correct way but keep in mind that generated url will expire in time. Also generated urls in that way can be slower because of redirects (Active Storage generates URLs which point back to the Rails application. When accessed, these URLs redirect to the actual service endpoint for the file).

If you want to generate permanent direct url to attachement, Active Storage is no go for now without some hackery.

There are couple of proposals to extend this feature in Active Storage: 
https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/34552#issuecomment-469530719

Comment: Could you present an example of the hackery to make this possible??

Comment: @K-Sato what comes to my mind is to create some custom show action in controller and in that action define some redirect `redirect_to url_for(@image.file)`. Then access this image/file via regular rails routes